# RestSharp - Your browser is currently set to block cookies

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using the restsharp library to execute requests, however some websites are returning me that cookies are not active in the browser I am using...

```
var url = @"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1535717589&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1%26RpsCsrfState%3d690f01d3-bd82-8c96-aa72-c30f2303ce0c&id=292841&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015";
var cliente = new RestClient();
cliente.CookieContainer = Cookies.Cookies; //re-use cookies
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
cliente.Execute(request);
```

Response

```
We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.
```

Comment: Where did `Cookies.Cookies` come from? The documentation mentions creating a new CookieContainer prior to the first request.

Comment: Maybe check that the value of Cookies.Cookies is valid.  According to the docs, if you set that CookieContainer to `new System.Net.CookieContainer()` the first time it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, even creating a new instance of cookies, it returns this error. These are the cookies created MSPRequ=lt=154444564783&co=1&id=484544